# Holomorphic vector field on Fano Kähler–Einstein manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact Fano Kähler–Einstein manifold, and $V$ a holomorphic $(1,0)$ vector field on $M$. The Fano conditions say that $V = \nabla^{1,0} f$ for some smooth complex-valued function. By Matsushima's theorem, the Kähler–Einstein condition implies that $\operatorname{div} V = \Delta f$ is an eigenfunction of the complex Laplacian $\Delta$. My question is: would it be possible to take the potential function $f$ to be a real-valued function?

Comment: Please do not cross-post to math.SE without saying so.  That way, we can avoid duplication of effort.

Comment: sorry about that.should I delete one of them?

Comment: Just put up a link, so people can check to see if there is additional information or answers at the other site.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498782/holomorphic-vector-field-on-fano-kahler-einstein-manifold/499890#499890

Comment: See my answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143575/is-there-an-extremal-metric-on-toric-fano-manifolds-which-have-nonzero-futaki-in/269678#269678

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually, I just figure out an argument. Take any hol'c (1.0) vector field, say X, then Fano implies $X=\nabla^{1,0}f$, with complex valued f. And $div X=\Delta f$. Now let f=u+iv, then since div X is 1-eigenfunction of complex Laplacian, so is \Delta u and \Delta v, then by matsushima theorem, one knows that $\nabla^{1,0}(\Delta u)$ is also a hol'c v.f. Which has real potential $\delta u$. since the laplacian is an real operator in the kahler case.

Comment: See my answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143575/is-there-an-extremal-metric-on-toric-fano-manifolds-which-have-nonzero-futaki-in/269678#269678